# Rotations around the origin not a normal subgroup of the group of all isometries

Tags: group-theory, rotations, reflection, isometry

I have to prove this exercise for my math study:

With a rotation I mean {$\rho_{x}| x \in \mathbb{R^{2}}$} and $x$ is the angle of rotation.

Let $H$ be the group of all rotations around the origin, and $E(\mathbb{R^{2}})$  the group of all isometries in $\mathbb{R^{2}}$. Then $H$ $\subset$ $E(\mathbb{R^{2}})$. Prove that $H$ is not a normal subgroup of $E(\mathbb{R^{2}})$.

I think I should start the prove by taking an element of $H$, i.e. $\rho$, and an element of $E(\mathbb{R^{2}})$, let's say, a reflection $\sigma$, and prove that $\sigma\rho\sigma^{-1} \notin H$

I have really no idea about how I have to complete the proof. Could you please explain it to me? thanks in advance!

Comment: What definition of rotation do you use?

Comment: Let $\sigma$ be a rotation about the origin.

Comment: I added it in the question

Comment: I think you would do better to take $\sigma$ to be a translation, such as $(x,y) \mapsto (x+1,y)$. Just take $\rho$ to be some rotation (through $\pi/2$ for example), and do the calculation. To show that $\sigma \rho \sigma^{-1} \not\in H$, it would be enough to show that it does not fix $(0,0)$.

Comment: @Derek Holt Yeah, that sounds good, but I don't actually know how to combine translations and rotations. So could you help me with that calculation?

Comment: As I said, just calculate what $\sigma \rho \sigma^{-1}$ does to $(0,0)$ for some specific $\rho$. First apply $\sigma^{-1}$, then apply $\rho$, then $\sigma$. Why do you need help doing that?

Comment: @Derek Holt Ok, I think I can do that, but how do I have to show then that the solution doesn't lie in H anymore?

Comment: @Derek Holt I think I've done it. If I take the point (0,0) , the translation you said, and a rotation around pi, then the point (0,0) goes to (2,0). But how do I prove that this does not lie in H anymore?

Comment: Where, Peter, does $(0,0)$ go when you do a rotation around the origin?

Comment: Oh yes, I see it. It goes to itself, and not to (2,0), so it is not a rotation, and therefore not in H. Am I right?